# how to implement google analytics in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, sdk, google-analytics

I'm creating a blackberry application. i need to use google analytics to track usage of my application. Is it possible to implement google analytics( or any other similar to google analytics) in blackberry? any specific sdk?

Answer (score 1):

Google dosen't seems to provide one.

But RIM is providing [one](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/platform/analyticsservice/), it's  not Google, but it should do the job.

You could try to use [Analytics SDK](http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/docs/android/) for Android, but I don't think it's gonna work.

Comment: is RIM analytics service is free?

Comment: @Udhaya, You can read, do you ? The Analytics Service is available to BlackBerry app developers at
no charge for up to 25,000,000 server calls per month.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the approach suggested in [Displaying ads in your mobile AIR application](http://blogs.adobe.com/flashplatform/2011/05/displaying-ads-in-your-mobile-air-application.html) blog entry at Adobe.com.

While it is for AIR and StageWebView class, it might work for Java and BrowserField as well.

Answer (score 0):

No, Google has not yet released an SDK for native Blackberry apps. Currently only iOS and Android SDK's are available to track analytics natively through Google Analytics.

If you want to do this from a Blackberry App, you will have to roll your own implementation or wait for the awesome Google Analytics team to release an SDK for Blackberry.

Answer (score 0):

Please check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/24245118/380138, I have written a library, it uses the Measurement Protocol, its quite useful for blackberry os 5.x to 7.x, plus it gets the job done.

I've tested and so far, I haven't had any issue with it.