# Implementing Google Analytics in native BlackBerry Application

Tags: blackberry, google-analytics

I am looking for a way to push information to Google Analytics from a native BlackBerry App. The App is built towards BlackBerry 6.0 OS.
I made a simple Google search about it, but the discussions I found are only confusing. 
Can someone please clarify what the options are to do this? Is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate post of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912991/how-to-implement-google-analytics-in-blackberry

Answer (score 3):

You need a browser context to use javascript based implementation of Google Analytics.  Currently only iOS and Android SDK's are available to track analytics natively through Google Analytics.

If you want to do this from a Blackberry App, you will have to roll your own implementation or wait for the awesome Google Analytics team to release an SDK for Blackberry.

**Update**

You now have the option to use the [Google Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide) as well.  This would remove the need for a javascript browser context or a native SDK.

Comment: Thanks, but I am curious about one more thing. What if I built a webpage that I can request in the background (from BlackBerry App) and this web page pushes info to Google Analytics. This would simply be a page that I would call "http://mypage.com/request.php?action=Start_App". And then "request.php" calls relevant GA functions to send information.

Comment: Yes, something like that could work. Because you are using php, this may help too - http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/mobile/mobileWebsites.html

Answer (score 1):

As shanabus said, Google analytics sdk doesnt work for Blackberry. You could try Flurry analytics (free) at http://www.flurry.com/ .It is pretty good. I have been using it in all my apps and Its been working fine for me.

I am sure there are many thousand apps which uses flurry analytics.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this link https://bitbucket.org/folorunsho1/googleanalyticsforblackberry .. it uses the Measurement Protocol Developer Guide as described by Brian

Answer (score 0):

Google not released SDK for google analytics for Blackberry.Instead why don't you try
Blackberry Analytics
Check below link

http://us.blackberry.com/developers/platform/analyticsservice/

Comment: Thanks, yes I am aware of the Analytics Service provided by RIM. But the reason why I insist on Google Analytics is that I am building a BlackBerry version of an existing Android App. And the app uses GA to track behaviors of users. So, I want to track both apps from the same repository.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Measurement Protocol Developer Guide: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide

Simple http post calls to add measurements from your app, at the bottom of the page are the calls for app tracking (screen and events).

e.g.

```
v=1             // Version.
&tid=UA-XXXX-Y  // Tracking ID / Web property / Property ID.
&cid=555        // Anonymous Client ID.

&t=appview      // Appview hit type.
&an=funTimes    // App name.
&av=4.2.0       // App version.

&cd=Home        // Screen name / content description.
```